# How to hide file paths when running Python scripts in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Every time I run my code, the terminal at the bottom is displaying this long name (I think the file location) as well as whatever output it's supposed to display.

Is there a way to get that to go away?

This is what it looks like:

[image: (screenshot of what's going on)]

> ```
> administrator@Machintosh-2 Exercise Files Python % /user/bin/python3...
> Hello world!  
> administrator@Machintosh-2 Exercise Files Python %
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to hide the paths, because the VS Code Integrated Terminal is basically using your OS/system's underlying terminal. And running Python scripts on a terminal requires the following form:

```
<path/to/python/interpreter> <path/to/python/file>
```

If you want a "cleaner" console output, you could create a [debug/launch configuration for Python](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging), then set the [`console`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console) configuration to `internalConsole`:

**.vscode/launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "run-my-script",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/your_script.py",
            "console": "internalConsole"
        }
    ]
}
```

That would display the output in the **Debug Console** tab rather than the **Terminal** tab. There will be no more paths, just whatever your script prints out to the console.

**sample output**:

[image: Debug Console screenshot]

Unfortunately, if your Python code uses and requires manual `input()` from the user, using the **Debug Console** and the  `internalConsole` solution would not work. It will show this error:

[image]

There is no direct solution to that, to having a "clean" output and allowing manual user `input()`. You might want to consider instead reading your program inputs from a file or [passing them as command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1009860/2745495). VS Code supports passing in arguments (`[args]`) when running your script

```
<path/to/python/interpreter> <path/to/python/file> [args]
```

using the `"args"` option in the launch.json file. Here is a simple example with [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

**python code**

```
import sys

# This is always path to the script
arg_0 = sys.argv[0]

# Same sequence as "args" in launch.json
arg_1 = sys.argv[1]
arg_2 = sys.argv[2]

print(arg_1)
print(arg_2)
```

**.vscode/launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "run-my-script",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/your_script.py",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "args": [
                "89",
                "abc"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**sample output**

[image: Debug Console with command line args]

Comment: You are correct that there is no direct support to hide the file path.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest/quickest way I do this is by putting

```
print("\033c")
```

at the top of my file (or anywhere else where I want everything above that `print("\033c")` erased (so I can get rid of the textual noise my other print statements might be making).

In ASCII encoding the octal number `33` is the ESC (escape) character, which is a common prefix for terminal control sequences. In combination with `c` we have an old [VT100 reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20190624214929/http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) essentially asking the terminal to reset to default, thus erasing all that textual noise so we only see the output of our code.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and I found an alternative solution. It is possible to **clear the console** after starting the program with a simple line. This will remove the initial path output in the terminal as well:

```
from os import system

system("clear")
print("Hello World")
```

Comment: I tried something like this but still had but still getting output under the say Hello World like    dev@**********-Air pydev %