# How to hide the file path displaying in Visual Studio Code's terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

After I run my python code in the terminal, it displays a few paths in the 1st line and then the output of my code in the 2nd line. Can I hide the 1st line so I only see the output in the 2nd line?

```
C:\Users\Venyl\Desktop\VS CODE\Code 2020>C:/Users/Venyl/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/Venyl/Desktop/VS CODE/Code 2020/print('lol').py"
hello world
```

Comment: Put the path to python in windows environement variables at the and of PATH

Comment: The entire path of python.exe. Then you can call python from anywhere.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/MS7ZcH4 it just displays this now, it still shows the 1st line that is the path

Comment: Now in vsCode go to python extension setting. You can find close to the end "Python: Python Path" to put python.exe, and maybe python.terminal.executeInFileDir

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/QkPzDlN and now it just displays this lol

Comment: I can't do better. To run a python script, you have to write: python.exe scriptName.py, it's the minimum.

Comment: oh ok thanks anyways :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide file paths when running Python scripts in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176552/how-to-hide-file-paths-when-running-python-scripts-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 3):

1. You could use the following settings in `launch.json` in the `.vscode` folder, and `"console":` sets the way the code debugging results are displayed.

> `"console": "internalConsole",`

After setting it, the debugging result will be displayed in the "debug console" inside VSCode.

[image]

2. We could also set it as:

> `"console": "externalTerminal",`

and the debugging results will be displayed in the "cmd" window outside VSCode. It also only displays the debugging results:

[image]

3. VSCode uses by default: `"console": "integratedTerminal",` it displays the results in the VSCode internal terminal, and displays the current environment and the path of the running file.

Reference: [console](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console).

Comment: @jill Cheng I tried this with C language inside VScode it didn't work! I guess it's only for python

Answer (score 1):

If you use code-runner extension,

open settings.json (ctrl + shift + p then type settings.json) then add this

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python": "<console clear> && <python or your python version> -u",
},
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```

In my case i replaced

<**console clear**> with **clear** *(since i am on wsl)*

&&

<**python or your python version**> with **python3.10**

Comment: And this allows for user input also?  Not sure if its appropriate but can you post what your out put looks like ?   And the settings.json you created?

Comment: Yeah, you can input values. https://ibb.co/tpNKGmp (quick tip use oh my zsh to make the terminal even more minimal) is this what you are looking for? @Jarhead1775


*pressing the code runner RUN button will first clear the console and then runs your program.*

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works for displaying the output as desired however if you want to hide the long path

use prompt [text]

For example, the following command sets "> (greater-than sign)" as prompt

> prompt $g

if you want to return back to showing full path just type prompt and press Enter.

Answer (score -2):

Donwload code-runner extension in VsCode,
then unchecked `Code-runner:Show Execution Message` in setting of
code-runner extension.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYuxS.png)