# How to remove or hide path details and file name in VS Code terminal?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal

[image: Expected VS Code Terminal Look]

I want to remove the directory and file details while i run the program :

```
cd "/Users/purnendubikashjana/Visual_Studio/Preparation-Java/" && javac armstrong.java && java armstrong

    ₹ Preparation-Java ₿ cd "/Users/purnendubikashjana/Visual_Studio/Prepa
ration-Java/" && javac armstrong.java && java armstrong
371 is an Armstrong number.
1634 is an Armstrong number.
```

I want a clean terminal like below :

```
    ₹ Preparation-Java ₿
371 is an Armstrong number.
1634 is an Armstrong number.
```

Is it possible to get like this terminal in VS Code in Java or any other languages ??

Kindly see the attached image for reference.

Comment: I don't think what you want is easily possible. VS Code is showing the commands that are run, as if you had typed those yourself.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson yeah... but is it possible to clean vs code terminal as i said ??

Comment: I assume you'd have to have access to the source code of the extension that you're using, or write your own, so that you can add that conditional logic for Terminal output display.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide the file path displaying in Visual Studio Code's terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63758560/how-to-hide-the-file-path-displaying-in-visual-studio-codes-terminal)

Comment: @starball not yet.... and whoever is not getting my question and mark as not useful kindly read my question and see attached screen shot carefully then mark as useful or not. Don't go blindly. Thank You.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5633472/11107541

Answer (score 0):

This is how vscode works - use shell commands. If you must change, you can use the [**Code Runner**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension, then add the following settings, `Run Code` executes the program.

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```

[image]

Comment: yeah... but i want the folder name like ...     ₹ Preparation-Java ₿ Hello world!

Comment: Why is there such a need? Perhaps you can submit your feature request in vscode GitHub.

Comment: yeah already did... and need because of clean terminal and extra occupied spaces... maybe not exactly needed for someone... but while i work on split screen the terminal goes small and the prompt directory name takes almost the space after every run.

Comment: You can share the link here so more people will know what's going on.