# How to hide unwanted log messages on Visual Studio Code, running Java code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using Visual Studio Code to write Java programs.
Everything works fine except that I always get unwanted messages when I run the code.
For example, I created a very simple and basic Java project that contains a App.java file (in the src folder, default package):

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

I have installed the extensions Java Test Runner and Debugger for Java. If I press "Run", I get:

```
PS C:\Users\Light\Documents\J\JVsc>  cd 'c:\Users\Light\Documents\J\JVsc'; & 'c:\Users\Light\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vsco\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.28.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\javaTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\Ri.exe' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\Light\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\67e3f4593863e5815\bin' 'App'       7c280b6c994f0132b01b2\redhat.java\jdt_ws\JVsc_623e5815\bin' 'App'
Hello, World!
```

This is very bad to see, and I have to record the video for school purposes, and I don't want these messages to appear. I dont' even know if this is a debugger issue or not.

It seems that VSC calls "CD command" before running the program.
I have tried to change the launch.json setting "console": "internalConsole" but it does not solve the problem, what it happens with this setting set up this way is that NO output at all is shown.

If I digit "cd src" then MANUALLY call "java App.java" it prints Hello World without that message, but obviously I don't want to manually type the compile and run commands.

Comment: you can make a compound task

Comment: @rioV8 What is a compound task?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks

Comment: What am I supposed to do with compound tasks, and why do they solve this problem?

Comment: you can define the shell commands you want to run in different tasks and combine them in a compound task

Comment: related / dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61176552/11107541

Answer (score 1):

There are some workarounds:

1.Add this in settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.enableFileLinks": false,
```

[image]
which will show less scripts before output in integrated terminal.

2.Set `"console": "externalTerminal"` in launch.json, you'll get a external console and no scripts displayed befor the real output:

[image]

3.Install the extension **Code Runner** and add the following code in settings.json:

```
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but this way you can only get OUTPUT. In the output tab, you can write input: you get the error "Cannot edit in read-only editor". So if I am using i.e. Scanner with System.in, I can't use this solution. Can I fix it someway?

Comment: Yes, This is code runner disadvantage. and there's no way to hide all  scripts but just some workaround, also i edit my answer and please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Install code runner extension
2. go to File> preferences > settings
   search for "Code-runner: Run In Terminal" and enable it to accept input from scanner.
3. go to File> preferences > settings, then search for "Executor Map" > click edit in settings.json
   and add the following modification corresponding to the programming language, java for example:

Java : "**function prompt{ \">>\"} && clear && tput setaf 6 &&** cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt **&& echo `n && tput setaf 5**",

you can check my videos for detailed explanation

https://youtu.be/WM5iW8SyGpk

https://youtu.be/yq8j3AsEOL0

Answer (score 0):

The closest we can get is by clearing the terminal before code runner runs the code. To do that:

1. Use the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension
2. In your settings.json file, change the java value in code-runner.executor map so that it'll look like this:

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
"java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && clear && java $fileNameWithoutExt"
}
```

#### some screen shots:

1. [code runner not running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sncov.png)
2. [just hit the run code button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHt5X.png)
3. [cleared console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyiNf.png)
4. [answered questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Xnm.png)
5. [final output after everything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlfjE.png)