# How to get clear java output console in vscode

Tags: java

my pc is too slow to run ECLIPSE so I recently shifted to vs code for execution of java code. But in vs code console every time I get unwanted paths. how to remove and get a clean console automatically...?
help out, guys... thank you!

[Vs code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxI6x.png)

Comment: This is already answered You can follow the process here - [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297373/how-to-hide-unwanted-log-messages-on-visual-studio-code-running-java-code)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide unwanted log messages on Visual Studio Code, running Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297373/how-to-hide-unwanted-log-messages-on-visual-studio-code-running-java-code)

Comment: Yeah thak you! It worked.