# How to delete all the folders without deleting the directory itself

Tags: powershell, batch-file

The following code deletes everything in Desktop, Download and Documents including the folders themselves. Is there any way to delete all the folders inside, but not the folder itself?

```batch-file
echo cmd delete all files in folder
del C:\Users\shmuel_admin\Downloads\*.*" /s /f /q
del C:\Users\shmuel_admin\Desktop\*.*" /s /f /q
del C:\Users\shmuel_admin\Documents\*.*" /s /f /q
rd /s /q "C:\Users\shmuel_admin\Desktop"
rd /s /q "C:\Users\shmuel_admin\Downloads"
rd /s /q "C:\Users\shmuel_admin\Documents"
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command Clear-RecycleBin -Confirm:$false
echo Done!
```

Comment: You have missing doublequotes in your batch file example, and technically your powershell command line is not required, as it is not part of your reported problem. I have included the powershell tag however, as you may be better advised to use powershell for the emptying of the directories too.

Answer (score 1):

You're using PowerShell to empty out the Recycle Bin; why not use PowerShell for the entire job?

```
Write-Host "Deleting all files and subfolders..."
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\shmuel_admin\Downloads -Recurse | Remove-Item
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\shmuel_admin\Desktop -Recurse | Remove-Item
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\shmuel_admin\Documents -Recurse | Remove-Item
Clear-RecycleBin -Confirm:false
Write-Host "Done!"
```

...and that's it!