# Why is VS Code showing the path to the extension and the exe when running the code? And how to make it shorter?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a Python file and run the code

```
print ('hello there')
```

using Visual Studio Code IDE. However when I run this code, the terminal screen shows:

```
PS D:\Learning Python>  & 'C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'c:\Users\ADMIN\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.8.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '64817' '--' 'd:\Learning 
Python\learn_python.py'
Hello there
```

Could you please explain why is it showing the path of the extension and the exe? And how to make it shorter to

```
PS D:\Learning Python>" (the folder stored python file
```

Comment: the problem here looks like you saved your python file in the wrong directory

Comment: where to save python file in correct directory bro? I save .py file in D directory and .exe app in C directory which is default when I installed VSC and Python

Comment: It's just showing you the command it executed to run your script.  It's not a problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide file paths when running Python scripts in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176552/how-to-hide-file-paths-when-running-python-scripts-in-vs-code)

Comment: that is make sure the debugger can be called no matter what the current directory of the terminal is. If you don't want to debug (slower) use another run option `Run without debugger`

Answer (score 0):

Terribly sorry. this is how python extensions work. Because the VS Code terminal integrates the powershell or cmd terminal from the computer, it need to specify the Python path to use and the path to execute the script for.

If you don't like it, you can install the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension. Once installed, the execute code icon in the upper right corner of VS Code will have three options.

[image]

Select **Run Code**, the code result will be output in the **OUTPUT** window (only the result, no extra lines).

Select **Run Python File**, and the code results are output in the **TERMINAL** window as before.

The third **Debug Python File** is used as debug code.

For better use, it is recommended to add the following code to your `settings.json` file after installing the **Code Runner** extension:

```json
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```