# Shorten sources when running python file though bash in VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When run a Python file, by clicking this,

[image]

I will receive the location of the file before I get the answer:

[image]

So can someone tell me how to delete it or make it look better?

Comment: what is the purpose of copying the same text in the question? It does not help you to an answer, more likely it will be slow you down, don't tag it with the wrong subjects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide file paths when running Python scripts in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176552/how-to-hide-file-paths-when-running-python-scripts-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following two ways:

1. Use debug mode, and change `"console"` to `"internalConsole"`. Your `launch.json` will look like:

   ```
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Python",
                "type": "python",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/your_script.py",
                "console": "internalConsole"
            }
        ]
    }
   ```
2. You can use code-runner extension if you do not want to use debug everytime. Then add the following code to your settings.json:

   ```
   "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
   "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
   "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
   ```

   In this way, you can click the **Run Code** button in your first picture, and the path will not be displayed each time you run file, and the last run result will be cleared automatically each time you run if you use code-runner extension.