# Is it possible to make a line of script (print("\033c")) added by default to the beginning of Python files in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ansi-escape

In order to remove file path displayed in Terminal of VsCode I use
`print("\033c")`  at the first line of each of my Python script files. Is it possible to make this line be the first line of each Python script file by default?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176552/how-to-hide-file-paths-when-running-python-scripts-in-vs-code) solve your issue? Btw, code-runner extension can also do it. Adding these codes to settings.json:  "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
  "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
  "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Actually, I found the print("\033c") from the post you linked! I tried the method in the accepted answer, but it causes issue for input() function so I decided to simply erase the text by this line of script.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT About second part of your comment: I did it but it gives Syntax Error, not sure why.

Comment: The second method requires you to install the [code-runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I didn't want to disturb you. I still have the problem with blue lines of text. The script in my setting.jaosn is: 

``{
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },``

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Now that I installed Anaconda for ML programming, I used Spyder and it runs the script pretty quick without any issues. So problem is solved ;)

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Thanks! It's kind of you. Ok it makes sense, I'm going to do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how I solved the issue:
I needed to install Anaconda in my PC for Machine Learning purposes. After spending some times on writing python scripts on spyder and Jupyter Notebook, I hadn't any issue in program running. So I choose spyder over VsCode.

Answer (score 1):

You can do even better (somewhat opinionated whether this is really better) using [the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP):

> If this is the name of a readable file, the Python commands in that file are executed before the first prompt is displayed in interactive mode.

If you're using a `launch.json` file to define debugging profiles, then you can probably use [the `env` field](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes) to define `PYTHONSTARTUP` to point to a file that you define in your workspace that contains that line, like `"env": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/startup.py"`. If you're using the integrated terminal, use the `terminal.integrated.env.<platform>` settings.

Also, your choice of `ESC c` is a bit overkill I think. Do you really want to trigger a [Full reset to initial terminal state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Fs_Escape_sequences) when running any of your scripts? There are better solutions to hide a file path that gets printed by VS Code like simply clearing the screen, which you can do with [`CSI 2 J`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences) or `CSI 3 J` (`2` means clear entire screen, and `3` means to clear entire screen and wipe the scrollback buffer).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Actually, I'm new to programming and found the code "print("\033c")" on the internet. So as your suggestion on second part of the answer, I tried print('\033CSI2J') but it doesn't work. Can you please help me? (again, sorry if I'm newbie).

Comment: I believe it would be `\033[2J` (info courtesy of [the wikipedia article linked in the post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences))