# c++: How to hide file path in VS Code Terminal Output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Enter your name: " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello: " << name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How to hide the file path in the terminal and show only the output? I have seen tutorial but it's for python https://youtu.be/e4C7UQeq0mo?si=69vGyCfGLUNeMBbe, I'm not sure how to do it with c++.

karen@Cs-MacBook-Air-2 karen C++ % cd "/Users/karen/karen C++/" && g++ lessonCinCout.cpp -o lessonCinCout && "/Users/karen/karen C++/"lessonCinCout

**Enter your name:**

**karen**

**Hello: karen**

karen@Cs-MacBook-Air-2 karen C++ %

Comment: You don't.  That's simply not how it works.  That's your prompt, ready for another command.  Why do you think you want this?

Comment: the terminal looks so clutter with the file path...

Comment: you can change that by modifying `PS1` environment variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide file paths when running Python scripts in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176552/how-to-hide-file-paths-when-running-python-scripts-in-vs-code) it's a python question, but the workaround of printing the ANSI escape code for screen clearing generalizes to any language.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++; this is purely a setting in your shell. macOS - and many Linux distros - use zsh. You can install [ohmyzsh](https://ohmyz.sh) and from there you can install different themes which may or may not display the current path. **HOWEVER**: Not displaying the path you're currently in may have some major disadvantages. For example whenever you're using the `rm` command.

Answer (score -2):

1. Click the top task bar in Visual Studio Code.
2. Open Terminal.
3. Open New Terminal.
4. Then write file name and add .exe [Just like: hello.exe]
5. Then touch Tab button in keyboard.
6. View .\hello.exe
7. Finally click the Enter key and view the output.

Comment: You completely misunderstood the problem.