# How do I stop the the terminal from displaying the path when I run Java in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Terminal when I run Java code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNHfH.png)

I've looked up multiple videos and posts about this but they're mostly about Python and I've tried them but it doesn't work. I've installed the Code-runner extension and unchecked "Code-runner: Run in terminal" and it still doesn't work. I've also tried removing "cd $dir &&" from "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt" in the settings.json file but the path still shows in the terminal.

Comment: why make trouble about this, it runs, and this is the way VSC does the stuff, if you want something else use a different editor

Comment: answers from https://stackoverflow.com/q/61176552/11107541 can be generalized to solve this problem.