How to stop vscode from printing extra lines when running Java
I just installed vscode along with the coding pack for Java from the vscode website, and whenever I run a Java program, it prints two extra lines in the terminal, one with a "^C" and another one that's blank.
I've tried messing around with uninstalling the default java extensions and changing some of the settings but I can't get it to go away. Any help?


considering your reply to my link in your reddit crosspost, closing as duplicate

I have a feeling some people who stumble on this in the future may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/q/61176552/11107541 - something totally different.

you can try to download the plugin Code Runner. Once the download is complete, select the settings.json file. Set the following in the file:
 "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
    "code-runner.fileDirectoryAsCwd": false,
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "ruby": "C:\\Ruby23-x64\\bin\\ruby.exe",
        "go": "go run",
        "cpp": "clear && cd $dir && g++ $filerName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "perl": "perl",
        "python": "python",
        "javascript": "node",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac -encoding utf-8 $fileName && java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 $fileNameWithoutExt"
    },

Then save the settings and restart the vscode attempt.
Besides, you can try changing the settings for .vscode/launch.json. Change the console settings to "console": "internalConsole". This will allow it to output results in the debug console.
